# Why shouldn't we use both jspViewResolver and TilesViewResolver together?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles, apache-tiles

I created Spring MVC with Tiles project.

My controller returns a string "hello" which is a logical file name and I have jsp called as hello.jsp.

In tiles.xml I should have a definition named hello which extends a definition template. 
My basic definition is mapped to layout.jsp.

When I add the jspViewResolver, it takes me to hello.jsp, but if I comment it out it takes me to layout.jsp which is rendered based on the definition of hello in tiles.xml.

So, why we shouldn't have both jspViewResolver and tilesViewResolver together?

Comment: Both are instances of a `UrlBasedViewResolver` which simple construct a URL regardless of the actually existence of the view being request. Other `ViewResolver` like the `BeanNameViewResolver` don't return a view when it doesn't exists. Having multiple `UrlBasedViewResolver`s in your view resolver chain will make the last ones never called. As explained in the documentation of the class.

Comment: If you would have put this as an answer, I might have selected this as best answer. :)

Comment: The comment wasn't actually fully true, gave a bit more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Both the [`TilesViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles3/TilesViewResolver.html) and [`InternalResourceViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) or instances instances of a [`UrlBasedViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html). In general this means that the `ViewResolver` takes the given view name and tries to construct a URL out of it this URL is used to resolve a view, regardless of the actual existence of the view.

Depending on the Spring version (Spring >= 3.0) and used subclasses a check will be done to check the actual existence of the view. (See [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-3661?jql=text%20~%20%22UrlBasedViewResolver%20check%20existence%22) solved issue).

The only implementation not actually checking the existence of views (at the moment) it the `InternalResourceViewResolver` or plain `UrlBasedViewResolver` instances. When using this make this the last one (highest `order` property) in the chain of view resolver.

When you want to combine plain JSP with Tiles this should actually be possible by giving the `TilesViewResolver` an order of 1 and the `InternalResourceViewResolver` an order higher then 1 (2 for instance).

In earlier versions (Spring < 3.0) these checks aren't in place and the ordering will as such not have any effect.